# How do I render a component, not a page in NextJS?

Tags: react-router, components, next.js, react-router-dom

I am trying to fix a button in a NextJS app that is inside of the authentication. The app does not use pages for authenticated routes, everything is `/#` and I am trying to figure out how to route the Settings component from a button. The original developer did not want to have any page paths in authentication.

Is there a process like in React, such that I can route to a component not page?

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/settings'>
      <Settings />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
<Router>
```

I feel like withRouter might be the key, but I cannot find the path I need to the component.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you approch Is not the best for a nextjs app.
Anyway you can [disable the nextjs file system](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server#disabling-file-system-routing) routing in nextjs config and use a custom server

```
module.exports = {
  useFileSystemPublicRoutes: false,
}
```

Then you can use the react-router component.
Take a look at this [tutorial](https://dev.to/toomuchdesign/next-js-react-router-2kl8) to see a more detailed example.